# Create HTML from Velocity vm - how do you use CSS?

Tags: java, html, css, jersey, velocity

I write a REST based webapp (for Tomcat) and return HTML created from a Velocity template through JAX-RS (Jersey). I would like to use CSS in the HTML and do not know how to properly reference the external CSS file (which resides in the war).

My Velocity template is in `/src/main/webapp` in the folder `templates`. My `style.css` also resides in `templates`. I would like to reference it from the `vm`-file in way that it is recognised and loaded when I return the resulting HTML through my REST service.

What do I need to do to achieve this?

Comment: My client is using a browser.